# Invalid Keystore Format

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Cree el archivo key.jks, al momento de correr el comando flutter build appbundle me da este error
[image: Error consola flutter build appbundle]

El keystore se generó con este comando

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore key\key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias srg
```

Flutter doctor -v
[image: Flutter doctor-v]

Comment: esa ruta que muestra el error es la correcta? como generaste la key (parece que no fue generado correctamente) ?

Comment: Si es la correcta, es en donde esta mi key.jks. la key la genere con este comando "keytool -genkey -v -keystore key\key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias srg".

Comment: puedes ejecutar este comando y agregar la respuesta en tu pregunta: flutter doctor -v

Comment: Podrías probar con otro JDK para generar la key? veo que estás usando el OPEN JSDK 1.8,  bajate el java sdk 1.6, llega a la carpetea bin y usa el comando `keytool` que tiene el sdk

Comment: @diegoveloper 1.6 no es muuuuy viejo? Ya ni siquiera tiene actualizaciones de seguridad hace 3 años... keytool funciona en ambas versiones

Comment: @SebastianGonzalez sugerencia: procura usar texto en vez de imágenes. Lo otro: esa ruta al jks cuando creas el archivo sólo funciona si corres el comando desde la carpeta de la aplicación y la carpeta key existe. Revisaste que el archivo JKS existe y tiene la llave nueva? Y revisa esos problemas en cmdline-tools y corre flutter `doctor --android-licences` como te está diciendo que hagas...